# Where's the ca cert bundle on OSX?

Tags: macos, curl

I'm debugging some curl ssl configuration stuff and was wondering where the ca cert bundle is installed on OSX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there isn't one.

Install curl via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) to get one.

You can probably use [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as alternatives to MacPorts if you prefer.

Mac OS X's own Security Framework, used by Cocoa apps and the like, uses the Mac OS X Keychain-format files in...

```
/System/Library/Keychains/
/Library/Keychains/
~/Library/Keychains/
```

...to find trusted CA certs. I doubt Mac OS X's built-in `curl` has been modified to use those Keychain files though, so I'm not sure why Apple doesn't ship a CA cert bundle for `curl`.

Comment: After some digging, I would guess that `curl` uses the keychain certs because otherwise I'd have to use `-k` for everything. Thanks for pointing me at the keychains. I'm not really familiar with that part of OSX. I also discovered that you can export certs from keychains using the [security](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html) tool.

Comment: wget installed with MacPorts doesn't. I'm trying to find where it is.

Comment: Sure enough opening KeyChain Access I can see the list of all the CA certs that the system knows about, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

I have a good usable one at `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`; I believe that got installed via Homebrew's openssl package.  This isn't necessarily useful if you need to verify how other parts of the system work, but if you're doing some debugging that requires specifying a singular PEM file to use for verifying a certificate.

See also the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24675167/120999) for additional ways to get a PEM to use in this way.

Comment: macos_cert="/usr/local/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem" after response = requests.get("https://local.internal.host/status")

Comment: `/opt/homebrew/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem`