# wget cannot verify GitHub.com's certificate

Tags: macos, ssl, wget, homebrew

I am using macOS 10.15.7. I have installed wget via homebrew. My goal is to install [orpie](https://opensource.com/article/19/1/orpie) via [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org). opam uses wget. My installation of wget cannot find the certificates it needs. How can I resolve this problem?

The error I am getting is:

```
$ wget --content-disposition -t 3 -O /Users/jamesh/.opam/default/.opam-switch/sources/csexp.1.5.1/csexp-1.5.1.tbz.part https://github.com/ocaml-dune/csexp/releases/download/1.5.1/csexp-1.5.1.tbz -U opam/2.0.8

--2021-04-28 10:42:18--  https://github.com/ocaml-dune/csexp/releases/download/1.5.1/csexp-1.5.1.tbz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.112.3
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.112.3|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify github.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert High Assurance TLS Hybrid ECC SHA256 2020 CA1,O=DigiCert\\, Inc.,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `which wget` and `wget --version`?  I'm using wget 1.21.1 from homebrew, and `wget https://github.com/ocaml-dune/csexp/releases/download/1.5.1/csexp-1.5.1.tbz` works fine for me.

Comment: GNU Wget 1.21.1 built on darwin19.6.0.

Comment: Can you try the simpler wget example in my 1st comment?  I don’t know what the rest of those OPAM things do, so trying to “minimize” the problem. If that simple wget fails, my guess is that you have some kind of proxy/VPN and it’s interfering w. the GH cert.

Comment: Do you have a .wgetrc or an environment variable pointing to certs?

Comment: @jimtut I found an answer. There is nothing that is interfering with the cert. In my case, the cert was just not found. Even if I did the simple ```wget https://github.com/ocaml-dune/csexp/releases/download/1.5.1/csexp-1.5.1.tbz```, it would fail. Please see the answer I posted. If you have any comments on it, I would be interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by locating a .pem file that can be used by wget.

I ran:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e "p OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE"
```

which returned:

```
"/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem"
```

I then created a .wgetrc:

```
$ cat .wgetrc
ca_certificate=/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem⏎
```

which allows wget to work.

Additionally, there should be a cert.pem file in the homebrew installed openssl package. Mine was located at `/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem`. Assigning ca_certificate to this path also worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try1:

```
 sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates

 sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

Try2:
Create **~/.wgetrc** file and add to it:

```
ca_certificate=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little too long for a comment, so adding as an "answer", even though the Op's own answer is just fine.

I think the underlying problem is the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56984577/skip-wget-certificate-checking-in-opam

Your macOS version isn't that old (Sep 24, 2020 at the oldest, with several patches even after that), so I wouldn't have thought that your CA bundle would be out of date.  But, somehow wget isn't pointing to it.

Fixing it with the Op's proposed Ruby-created default-cert is clever, but shouldn't have been necessary.  Homebrew's wget has a dependency on openssl, which comes with a similar cert.pem file, see [Where's the ca cert bundle on OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/247686/wheres-the-ca-cert-bundle-on-osx).  It would be good to know if the Op's homebrew openssl is somehow missing this bundle.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675167/ca-certificates-mac-os-x for other ways to get a cert bundle.

Comment: I do have ```/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem```. I do have the folders ```/System/Library/Keychains/```, ```/Library/Keychains/```, ```~/Library/Keychains/```...but these don't have any .pem files. I assume you are referring to ```/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem```

Comment: I still find it odd that wget does not know how to find these certificates without the .wgetrc, an environment variable, or passing it directly on the command line.

Comment: Agreed!  But, homebrew's wget does work on my Mac without a .wgetrc file.  Best guess at this point: the way wget is compiled for my M1 Mac (and installed in /opt/homebrew, not /usr/local) allows wget to pick up the cert bundle it needs, without a .wgetrc file.  Would love to hear from other homebrew-based wget users to know for sure, though!

Comment: Curious...do you know which cert.pem file wget is using on your machine?

I started https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1385 ... perhaps someone knowledgable will see it.

Comment: No. I tried the strace and other suggestions in my links to see, but I couldn’t see anything like while running wget. Good idea to start that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Just apt-install the `ca-certificates` package before calling wget.